# Problem when trying to import data from a django directory

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I started a application in django with discord.py

My modules for discord.py is in same directory where is django application started.

Looks like this:

[image]

My problem is when I want to import a botlogic model, get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot.botlogic'; 'bot' is not a package
```

I've tried every possible way ... and I'm still getting this error
How should I proceed?

Comment: Do you have an `__import__.py` file in the `bot` directory?

Comment: try `import bot`
then do `bot.whatever` or `from .bot import importanything`

Comment: @Dauros no, how can I create ?

Comment: It's just an empty file (usually). Use your favorite code editor or the terminal the create it.